# Going deeper -- yield from inside yield

Tags: python, yield

Is there a one-liner to take a generator and yield all elements in this generator? For example:

```
def Yearly(year):
  yield YEARLY_HEADER
  for month in range(1, 13):
    # How can I rewrite the following two lines?
    for line in Monthly(month):
      yield line
  yield YEARLY_FOOTER

def Monthly(month):
  yield MONTHLY_HEADER
  for day in range(31):  # Yes, this is wrong
    yield 'Day %d' % day
  yield MONTHLY_FOOTER
```

Maybe there are better ways to rewrite this whole method?

Comment: I don't think there is, and I find your code perfectly readable the way it is now. Simple is better than complicated.

Comment: @Tim so close, but the correct Zen of Python quote is "Simple is better than complex" ;)

Comment: Though via transitive property (through the next part of the Zen, "Complex is better than complicated") ... I guess you get partial credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special syntax for this case.

What you want is described in [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/). It's been around for years, but I don't think it will make it into Python any time soon. The `for .. yield` is simple enough and the other changes it proposes are quite complex.

Comment: Python 3.2 is due out in the next couple of weeks. PEP 380 is actually slated for inclusion in Python 3.3, but that won't be out until late 2012.

Comment: Python 3.3 is now out, along with PEP 380 (yield from).

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools

def Yearly(year):
  return itertools.chain(*[(YEARLY_HEADER,)] + 
                         [Monthly(m) for m in range(1, 13)] + 
                         [(YEARLY_FOOTER,)])
```

Basically, making the `YEARLY_HEADER` and `YEARLY_FOOTER` into iterators, they can be chained with the monthly iterators.

Comment: Good point here.  Yes there is a one-liner.  As with most one-liners, it's harder to read.